# Take total cost from customer, then clear listbox. Listbox keeps previous data

Tags: c#, winforms

I have imported data from a Microsoft Access file. I have displayed 2 columns for item and price. If I select an item, and click total, it will give the total, tax, and subtotal of the order in separate textboxes. When I click my clear button to clear the text boxes and the order, it works fine. When I start a second order and print the total, it grabs the previous order's subtotal, tax, and total, and then adds them to the new order.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double sum = 0;
    double tax = 0;
    double total = 0;
    foreach (MenuItems items in OrderList)
    {
    sum += items.price;
    }
    tax = sum * MenuItems.tax;
    total = sum + tax;
    txtTax.Text = tax.ToString("c");
    txtSub.Text = sum.ToString("c");
    txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
}
```

This button is too add all of the items in the order, and print their values in currency.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtTotal.Clear();
    txtSub.Clear();
    txtTax.Clear();
    ListBoxOrder.Items.Clear();
}
```

This button is to clear the text from within the text boxes, and the list box. What am I missing to reset the previous "order" and too not have previous total, subtotal, and tax add together with a separate order?

EDIT:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace CafeWithDatabase
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Generic List to hold the Cafe items
    List<MenuItems> OurCafeMenu = new List<MenuItems>();
    List<MenuItems> OrderList = new List<MenuItems>();
    List<string> cafe = new List<string>();
    MenuItems item;
    int counter = 0;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            //Connection String to Access Database
            string conn_string = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= C:\\Users\\Vexum\\source\\repos\\CafeWithDatabase\\CafeWithDatabase\\CafeDatabase.accdb";
            OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(conn_string);
            //open connection
            conn.Open();
            //reader
            OleDbDataReader reader;
            //command to select all items from CafeItem table, with the connection to the database
            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * from CafeItems", conn);
            //execute the reader
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            //clear the listBoxMenu for any potential existing items in the box
            ListBoxMenu.Items.Clear();
            //while loop makes the reader Read the data and add to the generic list
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                counter += 1;
                item = new MenuItems();
                item.name = reader[0].ToString();
                item.price = double.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
                OurCafeMenu.Add(item);
            }
            //foreach loop puts the menu items into the listboxmenu
            foreach (MenuItems item in OurCafeMenu)
            {
                ListBoxMenu.Items.Add(string.Format("{0} --- ${1}", item.name, item.price));
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            label4.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
    //Button to exit the application, could also be this.Close();
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    } 

    //a button to clear the text boxes and the ListBoxOrder
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtTotal.Clear();
        txtSub.Clear();
        txtTax.Clear();
        ListBoxOrder.Items.Clear();
    }
    //The ListBoxMenu gets the selected index, and then puts it into ListBoxOrder
    private void ListBoxMenu_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int curItem = ListBoxMenu.SelectedIndex;
        MenuItems temp;
        ListBoxMenu.SelectedIndex = curItem;
        ListBoxOrder.Items.Add(ListBoxMenu.SelectedItem);
        temp = OurCafeMenu.ElementAt(curItem);
        OrderList.Add(temp);
    }
    //if you double click on an item in the ListBoxOrder, it takes it out of the box
    private void ListBoxOrder_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string i = ListBoxOrder.SelectedItem.ToString();
        ListBoxOrder.Items.Remove(i);
    }

    //button to calculate the total of the selected items
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        double tax = 0;
        double total = 0;

        foreach (MenuItems items in OrderList)
        {
            sum += items.price;
        }
        tax = sum * MenuItems.tax;
        total = sum + tax;

        txtTax.Text = tax.ToString("c");
        txtSub.Text = sum.ToString("c");
        txtTotal.Text = total.ToString("c");
    }
}
}
```

Sorry for not posting the whole code. OrderList is a collection to hold the items and their price. It then grabs the prices, and adds them to text boxes for subtotal, total, and tax. The ListBoxOrder is the listbox that the items go into to allow the person too see what is selected.

Comment: I see two different lists: OrderList and ListBoxOrder.Items.

Comment: Ah yes, the age old issue of having two variables with a too similar names :)

Comment: Oops, sorry. I'll post the whole code. OrderList is just a list to add data to ListBoxOrder.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of missing code here, but the first thing that crosses my eyes is that you are clearing a different list then what you're calculations are based on.

You're never clearing `OrderList`. Add `OrderList.Clear()` to your `button2_Click`.

Comment: Okay. Well, I already edited the post to show my whole code, but I guess that fixes it. I guess I thought that when I cleared the list box, it would not remember and previous data. Thanks a lot for your help, sorry for asking help on something so simple.

Comment: Yessir it did. Sorry for late response. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: @Vexumy You should definitely mark this solution as the answer :).